# Laravel Nova: Pivot Table with 3 relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-6

in my Laravel Nova project I have this Models:

```
- Ricetta
   -id

- Ingrediente
   -id

- UnitaMisura
   -id

- RicettaHasIngrediente (many to many, pivot table)
    -ricetta_id
    -ingrediente_id
    -qta
    -unita_misura_id
```

Code:

```
class Ricetta extends Model
{
public function ingrediente()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\Ingrediente', 'ricetta_has_ingrediente', 'ricetta_id', 'ingrediente_id')->withPivot('qta', 'unita_misura_id');
    }
}
```

```
class Ingrediente extends Model
{
        public function ricetta()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\Ricetta', 'ricetta_has_ingrediente', 'ingrediente_id', 'ricetta_id')->withPivot('qta', 'unita_misura_id');
    }
}
```

```
class UnitaMisura extends Model
{
        public function ricettaHasIngrediente()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\ricettaHasIngrediente', 'unita_misura_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

```
class RicettaHasIngrediente extends Model
{
        public function unitaMisura()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\UnitaMisura', 'unita_misura_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I think this structure is correct.
With Laravel Nova, I have defined all the fields and the attributes of the pivot table, but I can't use the unita_misura_id:

```
...
BelongsToMany::make('Ingrediente')->fields(function () {
        return [
          Number::make('Quantità', 'qta'),
          HasMany::make('unitaMisura', 'unitaMisura')
        ];
      }),
...
```

When I open the form qta value; unita_misura is not displayed.
Can you help me?
thanks!

Comment: I'm exploring this as well, what did you land on using?